# Selected index on change in Laravel vuejs

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js

How can I determine the selected index on the select2 when I change the option. The thing is I want to determine which select2 I've been selected and determined it though calling the id of the selected select.

I need to call this id in on change but it depends of the index of the select2

```
:id="'passenger-select-'+index"
```

[image]

*select 2 vue*

```
    <tr v-for="index in total" :key="index">
      <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{index}}</td>
      <td>
        <select  class="details-input form-control select2" :id="'passenger-select-'+index" :name="'pax_name_'+index">
          <option label="Label"></option>
          <option v-for="(result,index) in results" :key="index" :value="result.first_name + ' ' + result.middle_name + ' ' + result.last_name ">{{result.first_name}} {{result.middle_name}} {{result.last_name}}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input :name="'pax_des_'+index" class="details-input form-control" type="text" disabled v-model="designation"/></td>
      <td>
        <input :name="'pax_gen_'+index" class="details-input form-control" type="text" disabled v-model="gender"/>
      </td>
   </tr>
```

*Jquery on change*

```
 $('#passenger-select-').on('change', () => {
    alert("test" + index_selected);
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean

```
$('[id^="passenger-select-"]').on('change', e => {
  alert("test" + e.target.selectedIndex);
});
```

or

```
$('.select2').on('change', e => {
  alert("test" + e.target.selectedIndex);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response, it works well in the first select but since I've been using v-for in my select let say I have two select option, the second select option didn't show the alert. do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I do not use VUE. Try to `inspect` the second select to see if it has the same selector as the first. But why do you mix VUE and jQuery in the first place? Is the not a VUE method to do what you want?